# Как правильно писать платформо/компиляторо-специфичный код?

Tags: c++

Иногда нужно написать код, зависящий от особенностей конкретной ОС или компилятора.

Например, есть некоторая функция `foo`, и я хочу, чтобы при компиляции этой функции под Windows был подключён заголовочный файл `Windows.h`, и моя функция `foo` вызывала некоторые WinAPI-функции из этого файла.

Или, например, если я компилирую `foo` с помощью g++, то хочу, чтобы `foo` использовала некоторые интринсики, специфичные для данного компилятора.

Как это правильно/надёжно/просто/принято реализовывать? Как функция `foo` может определить окружение, в котором она компилируется?

Comment: вам это надо? https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/j/guide-to-predefined-macros-in-c-compilers-gcc-clang-msvc-etc..html

Comment: ifdef-ы и, если платформенного кода много, выносите в отдельные файлы с соответствующим названием

Comment: @Zhihar, да, похоже это то, что мне нужно, спасибо!

Comment: Посмотреть все макросы, доступные при компиляции -- `gcc/g++ -E -dM - </dev/null`

Comment: Дополнительно. В процессе установки вы можете создать файл (обычно `configure.h`), содержащий все необходимые для условной трансляции собственные макросы. Он создается с  помощью набора тестовых программ, которые транслируются-запускаются в ходе установки и проверяют наличие той или иной фичи.  По этим  результатам, написанный вами скрипт (обычно часть Makefile) помещает  в configure.h   те или иные значения макросов.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте что-то типа такого

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNIX)
/* windows */
#elif defined(UNIX) && !defined(WIN32)
/* linux */
#else
/* other */
#endif
```

Comment: Макросы не те. Проверил на MinGW, `WIN32` пропадает при добавлении любого флага `-std=c++xx`. Вместо него лучше взять `_WIN32`. Макрос `UNIX` на моей убунте не стоит, гугл подсказывает, что нужно использовать `__linux__`. Ну и проверку, что оба макроса не стоят одновременно я бы вынес в какое-то одно место, и выдавал `#error` в этом случае.

Comment: Вместо `UNIX` обычно определены `unix` и/или `__unix__` , а также `__unix` (в Linux еще и `linux`, `__linux__`, `__gnu_linux__`  и `__linux`)